# Logstash is not pushing data to elasticsearch

Tags: logstash, elk

I am new to ELK stack and wants to try out some experiments. below log is spinning  but not pushing any data to elasticsearch. any help is appriciated

```
[2019-12-02T16:20:50,953][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
.[2019-12-02T16:20:51,897][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:20:51,907][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2019-12-02T16:20:52,042][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-12-02T16:20:52,043][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
.[2019-12-02T16:20:52,902][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
.[2019-12-02T16:20:53,905][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:20:54,211][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][test] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
.[2019-12-02T16:20:54,910][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:20:55,611][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][another_test] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
.[2019-12-02T16:20:55,912][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
.[2019-12-02T16:20:56,919][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:20:56,920][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
[2019-12-02T16:20:57,050][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-12-02T16:20:57,050][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
.[2019-12-02T16:20:57,924][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
.[2019-12-02T16:20:58,928][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:20:59,212][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][test] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
.[2019-12-02T16:20:59,930][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:00,611][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][another_test] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
.[2019-12-02T16:21:00,935][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:01,927][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
.[2019-12-02T16:21:01,938][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:02,054][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-12-02T16:21:02,055][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
.[2019-12-02T16:21:02,943][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
.[2019-12-02T16:21:03,948][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:04,212][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][test] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
.[2019-12-02T16:21:04,948][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:05,611][DEBUG][org.logstash.execution.PeriodicFlush][another_test] Pushing flush onto pipeline.
.[2019-12-02T16:21:05,953][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:06,933][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] One or more required cgroup files or directories not found: /proc/self/cgroup, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct, /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
.[2019-12-02T16:21:06,956][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
[2019-12-02T16:21:07,060][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2019-12-02T16:21:07,060][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
.[2019-12-02T16:21:07,960][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
.[2019-12-02T16:21:08,965][DEBUG][logstash.filters.sleep   ][test] Sleeping {:delay=>1}
```

Comment: Please, share your pipeline and a sample of your data.

Comment: - pipeline.id: test
    pipeline.workers: 1
    pipeline.batch.size: 1
    config.string: "input { generator {} } filter { sleep { time => 1 } } output { stdout { codec => dots } }"
  - pipeline.id: another_test
    queue.type: persisted
    path.config: "/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/logstash-full/myconfig.cfg"

Comment: input {
    file {
        path => "/usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/logstash-full/logstash-tutorial.log"
        start_position => beginning  
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
    geoip {
        source => "clientip"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    codec =>json  
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "Eshwar_logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
   
}

Comment: @EshwaraC, did you happen to figure out what could be the problem